# Maximize/Restore buttons in the title bar are disabled in a QMainWindow - pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I was just creating my window in the Qt Designer, when I had finished it I noticed that even opening it from a .py file, the maximize and restore buttons in the title bar are disabled, they appear in there but I can't click it. I am using Windows 10 by the way. It appears like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP8ja.jpg)

I found some solutions using:

`self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint)` `self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)`

but they don't work in my case.

Here's the complete code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *
import sys

class mainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mainWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('mainMenu.ui', self)
        self.show()

        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint) 
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = mainWindow()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: You've set a maximum (and probably a minimum) size of the window in Designer: obviously, if you specify a maximum size for the window, you cannot maximize it. Just restore those properties to the default by clicking the red "undo" arrow.

Comment: I can't really believe the answer was that simple, thank you so much!